Is the differential operator a generator of translations?
In quantum mechanics, it is said that momentum is a generator of translations using an approximation of the Taylor series of f(x-a), but momentum is defined in terms of the differential operator. So is the differential operator a generator of translations? And what does this mean more intuitively? The definition $\lim_{{h \to 0}} \frac{{f(a + h) - f(a)}}{h}$, does seem to translate f(x) by h, is this why this is? I can't seem to understand this intuitively in physics or math. In physics, momentum is proportional to velocity so it causes a particle to move and generates change in position over time? But the operator $\partial_x$ is over space purely and irrelevant to time?

The word generator is used in the sense of the theory of semi-groups of linear operators see this page for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0-semigroup . If you define $T_t f (x) = f(x + t u)$, then $\frac{1}{t}(T_t-T_0)(f)$ converges to $u\nabla f$ if $f$ is regular enough, when $t\rightarrow 0$

It's got nothing to do with velocity. The basic idea is$$T_hf(a)=f(a+h)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}h^nD^nf(a)=e^{hD}f(a)\implies T_h=e^{hD}.$$
